# How to use this method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I want to use one method for setting the textField.layer properties in one method in utility class. And want to call that method from viewController.

// Utility class

```
+(void) createRoundedBorderToView:(UIView*)view withColor:(UIColor*)color withCornerRadius:(float)cornerRadius withBorderWidth:(int)borderWidth{
    view.layer.borderColor = [color CGColor];
    view.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    view.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
}
```

But not getting how to call the method. I tried below, but giving error.

```
    CGFloat cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    [Utilities createRoundedBorderToView:_usernameTextField withColor:[UIColor clearColor] withCornerRadius:cornerRadius];
```

It is giving crash.

```
    [Utilities createRoundedBorderToView:withColor:withCornerRadius:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xdbf80
```

Comment: @SAKrisT Sorry not error but crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you missed param `withBorderWidth:(int)borderWidth`

you should call for example:

```
[Utilities createRoundedBorderToView:_usernameTextField withColor:[UIColor clearColor] withCornerRadius:cornerRadius withBorderWidth:1];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
+(void) createRoundedBorderToView:(UIView*)view withColor:(UIColor*)color withCornerRadius:(float)cornerRadius withBorderWidth:(int)borderWidth{
}
```

In above method to call you need to pass three parameters.
Like:-

```
[Utilities createRoundedBorderToView:_usernameTextField withColor:[UIColor clearColor] withCornerRadius:cornerRadius withBorderWidth:10];
```